# WF and ASPNET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, workflow-foundation

Is there a way to use MS WF interactively in ASPNET MVC?

Answer (score 5):

Did you see how WF and MVC were used inthe StoreFront example?

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-428.aspx